# Invalid label in trying to retrieve json from a restful webservice

Tags: jquery, html, cordova

Having this code when running it on firebug, in the console it will show **invalid label** and also my success callback doesn't fire. after fiddling my way to google about answers i found out that when using jsonp i need to parse the result and also i need to have a callback. Now i'm banging my head against the wall looking for possible answers. Can you help me with this one? THANKS.

```
    $.ajax( {
        url: 'http://localhost:8732/Service1/data/10',
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        processdata:true,
        jsonpCallback: 'mycallback',
        success : function(data) {

           var json = $.parseJSON(data);
           $('#items').html(json);
           alert(json);

        },
        error : function(req, status, ex) {

          alert("Lol" + ex);

        }
        });
      }
```

Also the `alert("Lol"+ex)` will prompt `LoljQuery16403233689395911671_1329386795307` was not called"

Comment: Also the Alert("lol"+ex) will prompt "LoljQuery16403233689395911671_1329386795307 was not called"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **jsonpString**
>
> Override the callback function name in a jsonp request. This value
>   will be used instead of 'callback' in the 'callback=?' part of the
>   query string in the url. So {jsonp:'onJSONPLoad'} would result in
>   'onJSONPLoad=?' passed to the server. As of jQuery 1.5, setting the
>   jsonp option to false prevents jQuery from adding the "?callback"
>   string to the URL or attempting to use "=?" for transformation. In
>   this case, you should also explicitly set the jsonpCallback setting.
>   For example, { jsonp: false, jsonpCallback: "callbackName" }
>
> **jsonpCallbackString, Function**
>
> Specify the callback function name for a JSONP request. This value
>   will be used instead of the random name automatically generated by
>   jQuery. It is preferable to let jQuery generate a unique name as it'll
>   make it easier to manage the requests and provide callbacks and error
>   handling. You may want to specify the callback when you want to enable
>   better browser caching of GET requests. As of jQuery 1.5, you can also
>   use a function for this setting, in which case the value of
>   jsonpCallback is set to the return value of that function

**Code Sample:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>img{ height: 100px; float: left; }</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="images">

</div>
<script>
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?",
  {
    tags: "cat",
    tagmode: "any",
    format: "json"
  },
  function(data) {
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
      $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");
      if ( i == 3 ) return false;
    });
  });</script>

</body>
</html>
```

References : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

**Edit : Code 2**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://server:port/path/to/file',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    cache: false,
    jsonp: '$callback',
    error: function (x, t, r) { alert(x.response.message); },
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data.d.results, function (i, val) {
            $("#results").append("<div>" + val.name + "</div>");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: just to clarify. i should put jsonp: false, jsonpCallback: "success", on my code? because i did it and yet success was not called and i still have a invalid label error.

Answer (score 0):

Is the json valid at http://localhost:8732/Service1/data/10? stick it in: http://jsonlint.com/. You could also try catching the error by doing:

```
var request = $.ajax( {
    ...
});

request.error(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: i added your code. this is the result in firebug. Object { readyState=4, status=200, statusText="success"}

Comment: and yes http://localhost:8732/Service1/data/10?  the json is valid on jsonlint.com